# Before proving or before being proven

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions, passive-voice, past-perfect, being

Today I encountered this sentence.

> Before him being proven guilty, everybody thought that he was innocent.

But I think there is another way to write it easily. Please correct me if I am wrong.

> Before proving his guilt, everybody thought that he was innocent.

And I want to know the difference between *before being proven* and *before proving*

Comment: Your version has tighter editing, but both say the same thing.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think your new version

> Before proving his guilt, everybody thought that he was innocent.

works, because it seems to say that *everybody* proved his guilt.

A better version might be

> Before he was proven guilty, everybody thought he was innocent.

Comment: This is clean writing. *Before him being proven* is already a scary start heading for no good.